# How to deal with read/write function for others file type in Java

Tags: java

I am doing a program which will receiving any file from my remote server, these files can be .doc, .pdf and some others file type. I will read the content in those files and write it into another new files with same file extension. But when i receive a .doc file from remote server and i try read the file and write into another file, it's show me something like this             `@²Ó\ç¨ Þ¢·S \Ò Þ¢·S \Ò PK          £  JT` in my test.doc. i have no idea on this issues, i try `PrintStream,BufferedWriter` or `PrintWriter` but unfortunately it's wouldn't help anything   
 This is my source code for read/write the file

```
         try
           {
             InputStream is1 = con1.getInputStream();
             BufferedReader read1 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is1));
             String data1 = "" ; 
             while ((data1 = read1.readLine()) != null)
             {
              PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("test.doc","UTF-8");
               pw.write(data1);
               pw.close();

              }
          System.out.println("done");
           }
          catch(IOException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

May i know what is the best way to do the read/write if we having difference file type ?

Comment: `.doc` files can't be read just like that. You need a third party library such as POI

Comment: how about .pdf file ??

Comment: you write the file as "UTF-8" - and I suspect it's not text-base - try binary!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These file types have binary data and should not be read as characters. (Also, note that you are creating a new `PrintWriter` every time through the `while` loop. This will never work.) Just deal with the binary data directly. Something like this (untested) might work:

```
InputStream is1 = con1.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is1);
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // or whatever size you want
int n;
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("test.doc");
while ((n = bis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
os.close();
bis.close();
```

Also, you should be using a [*try with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach (more concise, more expressive):

```
Files.copy(is1, Paths.get("test.doc"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```